# Byte Beat melody has no volume

Tags: no-mans-sky

Just put in a Byte Beat and connected it to a power system.  I noticed I didn't hear a melody, just drum beats.  Turned off the drums, and I have no sound whatsoever.  My melody sequencer has stuff on it, and it makes no sound.  My arpeggiator has stuff on it and it makes no sound.  What's going on here!?  How do i get a melody to play?

Comment: Did you really mean to tag this no man's sky?

Comment: Yes, No Man's Sky has something you can build called a Byte Beat that allows you to generate music for your base.  Crazy I know.  =D

Comment: ... apparently my propensity to build utilitarian and minimalist bases has left me at a disadvantage. ;)

Comment: Lol, my base is pretty ugly right now.  I'm new, so I cant tell you how much joy it gave me when I set up 3 solar panels and a battery so now my base is powered *all* the time.  The teleporter is on now.  My goal is to have my base play the mandalorian theme, but I'm not getting my hopes up.  =)

Comment: You should stick to a 2:1 ratio of solar panels to batteries btw. Of course it would be best to identify a hotspot _before_ setting up your base (and use an electro-magnetic generator), but if you're going to solar panel route, 2:1 is your ratio. (Also switches are definitely a plus unless you're using the prefabs.)

Comment: Thanks for the advice!  Working on getting ready to build an underwater base now, because they're cool.  Maybe we'll meet on the Anomaly sometime.  Cheers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I built a new one and it works perfectly.  Destroyed and rebuilt the old one and it too works perfectly.  Must have been a bug.  Unfortunately the Byte Beat relies a lot on procedural generation, so making the mandalorian theme is difficult.  I'm new to this though, so who knows.  Thanks!

Comment: Great to hear! Be sure to accept your answer so others know that it worked for you.